# Why VisualBasic (VB.NET) faster than C++ code in this example?

Tags: c++, vb.net, visual-c++, scientific-computing

I have been benchmarking an iterative calculation, a Lapalace equation solver for electrostatics, that uses the Jacobi method. I wrote the same algorithm in Visual Basic and C++ (and other languages too). For some reason, Visual Basic .Net came as the fastest. I don't understand why. Since C++ is compiled to bytecode, then I would expect it to be faster. I feel that my C++ is perhaps not optimised as it should. Any help understanding why C++ is not faster than VisualBasic would be appreciated. Thank you.

In the following codes, the iteration loop lasts about 2.8 seconds with Visual basic, and VisualC++ takes 4.8 seconds

**Visual Basic Code**

```
Imports System.Timers

Module Module1
    Const ARRAYDIM = 500
    Const iterationVMaxError = 0.001

    Sub Main()
        Dim PAArrayPotentials(ARRAYDIM, ARRAYDIM) As Single
        Dim PAArrayIsElectrode(ARRAYDIM, ARRAYDIM) As Boolean

        Console.WriteLine("SpeedTestEMLaplaceSolverVB")
        Console.WriteLine("Start generating electrodes and popuate 2D array")

        'Start generating electrodes
        For iy = 0 To ARRAYDIM - 1
            For ix = 0 To ARRAYDIM - 1
                PAArrayPotentials(iy, ix) = 0 'Default
                PAArrayIsElectrode(iy, ix) = False

                If ix = 20 And (iy > 150 And iy < 350) Then
                    PAArrayPotentials(iy, ix) = 1 'Default
                    PAArrayIsElectrode(iy, ix) = True
                End If

                If ix = 480 And (iy > 150 And iy < 350) Then
                    PAArrayPotentials(iy, ix) = -1 'Default
                    PAArrayIsElectrode(iy, ix) = True
                End If

            Next
        Next

        Console.WriteLine("Finished creating electrodes.")

        Console.WriteLine("Press enter key to start")
        Console.ReadLine()
        Console.WriteLine("Starting iterative Laplace.")

        Dim iteration As Integer = 0
        Dim maxerror As Single = 0
        Dim t0 = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew()

        Do
            maxerror = 0
            For iy = 0 To ARRAYDIM - 1
                For ix = 0 To ARRAYDIM - 1
                    If Not PAArrayIsElectrode(iy, ix) Then
                        Dim sum As Single = 0
                        Dim nvalues As Single = 0

                        If iy > 0 Then
                            sum += PAArrayPotentials(iy - 1, ix)
                            nvalues += 1
                        End If
                        If iy < ARRAYDIM - 1 Then
                            sum += PAArrayPotentials(iy + 1, ix)
                            nvalues += 1
                        End If
                        If ix > 0 Then
                            sum += PAArrayPotentials(iy, ix - 1)
                            nvalues += 1
                        End If
                        If ix < ARRAYDIM - 1 Then
                            sum += PAArrayPotentials(iy, ix + 1)
                            nvalues += 1
                        End If

                        If nvalues > 0 Then
                            Dim newval As Single = sum / nvalues
                            Dim vchange As Single = Math.Abs(newval - PAArrayPotentials(iy, ix))
                            maxerror = Math.Max(vchange, maxerror)

                            PAArrayPotentials(iy, ix) = newval
                        End If
                    End If
                Next
            Next

            iteration += 1

        Loop While maxerror > iterationVMaxError

        Dim deltaT As Long = t0.ElapsedMilliseconds

        Console.WriteLine("Completed, in " + iteration.ToString + " iteration cycles; deltat = " + deltaT.ToString + " miliseconds.")

        Console.WriteLine("Press enter key to close")
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

End Module
```

**Visual C++ code**

```
// SpeedTestEMLaplaceSolver2.cpp : This file contains the 'main' function. Program execution begins and ends there.
//
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <cmath>
#include <chrono>

#define ARRAYDIM 500

//Use normal arrays rather than the std::array
float PAArrayPotentials[ARRAYDIM][ARRAYDIM];
bool PAArrayIsElectrode[ARRAYDIM][ARRAYDIM];

int main()
{
    std::cout << "SpeedTestEMLaplaceSolver2.cpp using standard arrays float PAArrayPotentials[PAWIDTH][PAHEIGHT];\n";
    std::cout << "500 x 500 with 2 electrodes at position 20 and 480. Height of 200 each.\n" <<
        "Left electrode at + 1 V and right electrode at - 1V.\n" <<
        "iterationVMaxError = 1e-3.\n";

    const float iterationVMaxError = 1e-3f;

    //Fill array with zeros and electrodes
    std::cout << "Start generating electrodes and PA.\n";
    for (int iy = 0; iy < ARRAYDIM; iy++) {
        for (int ix = 0; ix < ARRAYDIM; ix++) {
            float * pmyPointPot = &PAArrayPotentials[iy][ix]; //get a reference to the point
            bool * pmyPointIsEl = &PAArrayIsElectrode[iy][ix]; //get a reference to the point

            //Default for all points
            *pmyPointPot = 0;
            *pmyPointIsEl = false;

            //Electrode
            if (ix == 20 && (iy > 150 && iy < 350 )) {
                *pmyPointPot = 1;
                *pmyPointIsEl = true;
            }
            if (ix == 480  && (iy > 20 && iy < 350 ) ) {
                *pmyPointPot = -1;
                *pmyPointIsEl = true;
            }
        }
    }

    std::cout << "Completed generating electrodes and PA.\n";

    std::cout << "Type a letter and enter key to start calculation.\n";
    char stemp[80];
    std::cin >> stemp;
    std::cout << "Start iterative laplace\n";

    auto starttime = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    long iteration = 0;

    float perror;
    //Convergence routine
    do {
        perror = 0; //resets
        
        for (int iy = 0; iy < ARRAYDIM; iy++) {
            for (int ix = 0; ix < ARRAYDIM; ix++) {

                if (!PAArrayIsElectrode[iy][ix]) {
                    //Makes the new value the average of surrounding values
                    float sum = 0;
                    float nvalues = 0;
                    if (iy > 0) {
                        sum += PAArrayPotentials[iy - 1][ix];
                        nvalues++;
                    }
                    if (iy < ARRAYDIM - 1) {
                        sum += PAArrayPotentials[iy + 1][ix];
                        nvalues++;
                    }
                    if (ix > 0) {
                        sum += PAArrayPotentials[iy][ix - 1];
                        nvalues++;
                    }
                    if (ix < ARRAYDIM - 1) {
                        sum += PAArrayPotentials[iy][ix + 1];
                        nvalues++;
                    }
                    if (nvalues > 0) {
                        float newVal = sum / nvalues;
                        float vchange = fabs(newVal - PAArrayPotentials[iy][ix]);
                        perror = fmax(vchange, perror);

                        PAArrayPotentials[iy][ix] = newVal; //Set the new calculated value
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        iteration++;
        //std::cout << "iteration: " << iteration << " , perror= " << perror << std::endl;
    } while (perror > iterationVMaxError );

    auto endtime = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

    std::cout << "Completed, in " << iteration << " iteration cycles; deltat = " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(endtime - starttime).count() << " miliseconds" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `Since C++ is compiled to bytecode`-> nope

Comment: VB.NET is compiled to bytecode.  Not C++.

Comment: Did you compile with optimisations turned on? (`/O2`)?  Do both examples do the same work (same number of iterations)?  If you only care about making it run faster then consider the algorithm you are using, multiple nested loops with dozens of branching statements inside it is a great way to slow down code.

Comment: C++ is compiled to machine code that runs directly on the CPU.  VB.NET is compiled to an intermediate byte code that has to be interpreted at runtime into CPU instructions.

Comment: For what it's worth, that code takes 1680ms to run on my machine with clang and `-O3`. If you need this *fast* forget about the CPU and go for a GPU-based solution if you can. I bet a GPU could do this in <10ms.

Comment: On an i7-5000 CPU, this took 2681ms running Visual Studio 2019 in release mode.

Comment: On my pokey laptop with DDR3 ram and .NET 4.8, x86: vb.net 12352, c++:3662. x64: vb.net 3050, c++:2811.  Comparing multi-dimensional array access in vb.net with jagged array access in c++ is difficult, albeit that there are no great ways to make jagged arrays pay-off.  Explaining a x2 slowdown in c++ is going to be difficult, turn off the installed anti-malware product.

Comment: Note that in VB.Net,  the array sizing parameter (`ARRAYDIM ` in your code) specifies the upper bound of the array, not the number of elements in the array.  The array indexing starts at zero and goes to `ARRAYDIM `, so there are `ARRAYDIM  + 1` elements in the array.

Comment: To answer M.A. I compiled C++ with optimisations turned on, for fast code /O2.

Comment: Sorry, correct, C++ compiles to to machine code, and VB.net compiles to CIL
To answer M.A. I compiled C++ with optimisations turned on, for fast code /O2. And, indeed, both C++ and VB give the same number of iterations and results.
Hans Passant, your results are interesting, and contrary to my results, in the sense that C++ is faster than VB.net. My CPU is AMD FX6300 6core. I don't have any anti-malware apart from the windows defender.
TnTinMn, thank you for the suggestion. I fixed my code, but still get the same timings.

Comment: Note that while VB is compiled to byte code initially, at run-time, the just-in-time compiler will compile to machine code.  This JIT pass does impact performance, but upon program startup and/or routine entry; by the point you're measuring, you're past the JIT overhead.  The main thing I would expect to still lead to slower performance in VB is that it will still be checking for out-of-bounds array access, whereas using native arrays in C++ is completely unchecked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. After digging further as to why VB.Net was faster than C++, I hypothesised that the issue could be due to the C++ compiler.

I downloaded the Intel C++ compiler and recompiled the program.
I also changed the array to 1024x1024 size and the criteria to stop the iteration to maxchange=1e-4. All developed under MS Visual Studio 2019 community.

Benchmarking results are:

```
Visual C++ (MS): 66356 miliseconds
Visual C++ (Intel): 39013 miliseconds
VB.Net : 62847 miliseconds
```

So, now C++ compiled code (intel) is faster.

And here is the code I used

```
// SpeedTestEMLaplaceSolver2.cpp : This file contains the 'main' function. Program execution begins and ends there.
//
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <cmath>
#include <chrono>

#define ARRAYDIM 1024

//Use normal arrays rather than the std::array
float PAArrayPotentials[ARRAYDIM][ARRAYDIM];
bool PAArrayIsElectrode[ARRAYDIM][ARRAYDIM];

int main()
{
    const float iterationVMaxError = 1e-4f;

    std::cout << "SpeedTestEMLaplaceSolver2.cpp using standard arrays float PAArrayPotentials[PAWIDTH][PAHEIGHT];\n";
    std::cout << "Dimensions: " << ARRAYDIM << "x" << ARRAYDIM << " , iterationVMaxError = " << iterationVMaxError << "\n" <<
        "Left electrode at + 1 V and right electrode at - 1V.\n";

    const int  pos_1_4 = (int)floor(ARRAYDIM / 4);
    const int  pos_3_4 = (int)floor(ARRAYDIM * 3 / 4);

    //Fill array with zeros and electrodes
    std::cout << "Start generating electrodes and PA.\n";
    for (int iy = 0; iy < ARRAYDIM; iy++) {
        for (int ix = 0; ix < ARRAYDIM; ix++) {
            float * pmyPointPot = &PAArrayPotentials[iy][ix]; //get a reference to the point
            bool * pmyPointIsEl = &PAArrayIsElectrode[iy][ix]; //get a reference to the point

            //Default for all points
            *pmyPointPot = 0;
            *pmyPointIsEl = false;

            //Electrode
            if (ix == pos_1_4 && (iy > pos_1_4 && iy < pos_3_4)) {
                *pmyPointPot = 1;
                *pmyPointIsEl = true;
            }
            if (ix == pos_3_4 && (iy > pos_1_4 && iy < pos_3_4) ) {
                *pmyPointPot = -1;
                *pmyPointIsEl = true;
            }
        }
    }

    std::cout << "Completed generating electrodes and PA.\n";

    std::cout << "Type a letter and enter key to start calculation.\n";
    char stemp[80];
    std::cin >> stemp;
    std::cout << "Start iterative laplace\n";

    auto starttime = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    long iteration = 0;

    float maxerror =0;
    //Convergence routine
    do {
        maxerror = 0; //resets
        
        for (int iy = 0; iy < ARRAYDIM; iy++) {
            for (int ix = 0; ix < ARRAYDIM; ix++) {

                if (!PAArrayIsElectrode[iy][ix]) {
                    //Makes the new value the average of surrounding values
                    float sum = 0;
                    float nvalues = 0;
                    if (iy > 0) {
                        sum += PAArrayPotentials[iy - 1][ix];
                        nvalues++;
                    }
                    if (iy < ARRAYDIM - 1) {
                        sum += PAArrayPotentials[iy + 1][ix];
                        nvalues++;
                    }
                    if (ix > 0) {
                        sum += PAArrayPotentials[iy][ix - 1];
                        nvalues++;
                    }
                    if (ix < ARRAYDIM - 1) {
                        sum += PAArrayPotentials[iy][ix + 1];
                        nvalues++;
                    }
                    if (nvalues > 0) {
                        float newVal = sum / nvalues;
                        float vchange = fabs(newVal - PAArrayPotentials[iy][ix]);
                        maxerror = fmax(vchange, maxerror);

                        PAArrayPotentials[iy][ix] = newVal; //Set the new calculated value
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        iteration++;
        //std::cout << "iteration: " << iteration << " , perror= " << perror << std::endl;
    } while (maxerror > iterationVMaxError );

    auto endtime = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

    std::cout << "Completed, in " << iteration << " iteration cycles; deltat = " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(endtime - starttime).count() << " miliseconds" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

And the VB.Net

```
Imports System.Timers

Module Module1
    Const ARRAYDIM = 1024
    Const iterationVMaxError = 0.0001 ' 1e-4

    Sub Main()
        Dim PAArrayPotentials(ARRAYDIM - 1, ARRAYDIM - 1) As Single
        Dim PAArrayIsElectrode(ARRAYDIM - 1, ARRAYDIM - 1) As Boolean

        Console.WriteLine("SpeedTestEMLaplaceSolverVB")
        Console.WriteLine("Dimensions: " + ARRAYDIM.ToString + "x" + ARRAYDIM.ToString + " , iterationVMaxError = " + iterationVMaxError.ToString)
        Console.WriteLine("Start generating electrodes and popuate 2D array")

        Dim pos_1_4 As Integer = Int(ARRAYDIM / 4)
        Dim pos_3_4 As Integer = Int(ARRAYDIM * 3 / 4)

        'Start generating electrodes
        For iy = 0 To ARRAYDIM - 1
            For ix = 0 To ARRAYDIM - 1
                PAArrayPotentials(iy, ix) = 0 'Default
                PAArrayIsElectrode(iy, ix) = False


                If ix = pos_1_4 And (iy > pos_1_4 And iy < pos_3_4) Then
                    PAArrayPotentials(iy, ix) = 1 'Default
                    PAArrayIsElectrode(iy, ix) = True
                End If

                If ix = pos_3_4 And (iy > pos_1_4 And iy < pos_3_4) Then
                    PAArrayPotentials(iy, ix) = -1 'Default
                    PAArrayIsElectrode(iy, ix) = True
                End If

            Next
        Next

        Console.WriteLine("Finished creating electrodes.")

        Console.WriteLine("Press enter key to start")
        Console.ReadLine()
        Console.WriteLine("Starting iterative Laplace.")

        Dim iteration As Integer = 0
        Dim maxerror As Single = 0
        Dim t0 = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew()

        Do
            maxerror = 0
            For iy = 0 To ARRAYDIM - 1
                For ix = 0 To ARRAYDIM - 1
                    If Not PAArrayIsElectrode(iy, ix) Then
                        Dim sum As Single = 0
                        Dim nvalues As Single = 0

                        If iy > 0 Then
                            sum += PAArrayPotentials(iy - 1, ix)
                            nvalues += 1
                        End If
                        If iy < ARRAYDIM - 1 Then
                            sum += PAArrayPotentials(iy + 1, ix)
                            nvalues += 1
                        End If
                        If ix > 0 Then
                            sum += PAArrayPotentials(iy, ix - 1)
                            nvalues += 1
                        End If
                        If ix < ARRAYDIM - 1 Then
                            sum += PAArrayPotentials(iy, ix + 1)
                            nvalues += 1
                        End If

                        If nvalues > 0 Then
                            Dim newval As Single = sum / nvalues
                            Dim vchange As Single = Math.Abs(newval - PAArrayPotentials(iy, ix))
                            maxerror = Math.Max(vchange, maxerror)

                            PAArrayPotentials(iy, ix) = newval
                        End If
                    End If
                Next
            Next

            iteration += 1

        Loop While maxerror > iterationVMaxError

        Dim deltaT As Long = t0.ElapsedMilliseconds

        Console.WriteLine("Completed, in " + iteration.ToString + " iteration cycles; deltat = " + deltaT.ToString + " miliseconds.")

        Console.WriteLine("Press enter key to close")
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

End Module
```